# Program Compiles, Runs, but doesn't end in DevC++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I wrote a program to sum all odd numbers less than or equal to N. It's not the most efficient or eloquent program, but it works in the compiler on Codepad.org and does not work in DevC++. Usually when a program I wrote is stuck in some kind of infinite loop the program crashes in DevC++ and Windows stops it and lets me know.

Here, the program compiles and runs, but just sits with the cursor blinking and does nothing. Windows doesn't stop it, nothing happens, the program doesn't finish, no matter for how long I let it sit. I'm guessing this is a problem with DevC++ unless it's a problem with my code that Codepad overlooks. Will anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int odd(int N)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        while((i % 2) != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int N;

    cout << "Pick a value: ";

    cin >> N;

    cout << "The sum of all numbers <= to " << N << " is: " << odd(N);

    return 0;
}
```

---

I've made the suggested change to an if-statement and the same problem is occuring:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int odd(int N)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        if ((i % 2) != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }

    return sum; 
}


int main()
{
    int N;

    cout << "Pick a value: ";

    cin >> N;

    cout << "The sum of all odd numbers <= to " << N << " is: " << odd(N); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: it doesn't *really* run correctly on codepad.org; you cannot enter `N`, and it uses `0` instead. If you add `N=5`, for example, codepad.org issues a timeout after a while.

Comment: I know, that's why I made the comment that it may have been something codepad overlooks because it uses 0 and not other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  while((i % 2) != 0)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
```

This is a infinite loop.Because if `(i % 2 != 0)` is true then the program will increment sum again and again.What you are probably looking to do is have an `if` statement instead of `while`

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean and I changed it to an if statement instead, however the same thing keeps happening. Even if I comment out everything except for main and just ask it to print out 'N' after the user enters 'N' the same thing happens.

Comment: Okay, I've realized what part of the problem is. No matter what changes I make and compile, or even if I try to save the file, when I hit "run" it doesn't run with those changes or saves, just the original  code from the first time I ran & compiled it. Because when I copied and pasted your code into main and commented out everything I originally put, it still prints "Pick a number" when that has been commented out.

Comment: @Sarah What you want to do is click on **Compile & Run** and not **Run**. **Run** simply runs the latest built executable while **Compile & Run** will compile your latest code into a new executable before running it.

Comment: I know, I have been clicking Compile & Run the entire time.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but here's a document with a screen shot of what's happening.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xX1J2Qe-oMewZ9M1i9XCexKmrMQQF0o1kCt0DPLU--o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not particularly aware of how this is done in DevC++ but there is the universal approach : just close devC++ and open only the file which contains my solution and it should work just fine.

Comment: Alright well for some odd reason it wouldn't work for that specific new source file... I made another and it printed the number 4 and exited. I took an old source file, deleted everything, pasted your code and compiled & ran and it printed 4 again and exited, as it should. Not really sure why it won't work inside the original source file, maybe I just need to restart DevC++ or my computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the edit is working, please try deleting the old output file and rebuilding and re-compile the entire program.
The output seems to be as follows:

Pick a value: 52

The sum of all odd numbers <= to 52 is: 676

Process exited after 1.034 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Add your code and explain the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the window of the previous run is closed else the compiler will not recompile but just runs the previous version before you changed it.you may see this as an error stated at bottom in debug mode.
the while() is an infinite loop because i is not changed inside the while()  or its {} so use if

Comment: more elegant: if(N%2==0) m=N-1;else m=N; sum=0; for(i=1;i<=m;i+=2) sum+=i;